# TIBCO JMS Error Invalid Session Status Code <20>

Tags: c++, session, queue, tibco

i am going to develop a JMS Queue **Sender** Program with C/C++ and TIBCO Libraries. I want to send a Text Message via the corresponding Queue. I am getting unfortunately following Error Message. You can be sure that all Attributes and Login Credentials are correct

**TIBCO Error Invalid Session Status Code <20>**

My Code looks like following

```
// Attributes
    tibems_status m_tStatus; // Returncodes
    tibemsErrorContext m_tErrorContext; // Contains errormsgs
    tibemsConnection m_tConnection; // The Tibco connection
    tibemsDestination m_tDestination; // Tibco Destination
    tibemsSession m_tSession; // Tibco Session
        tibemsTextMsg m_tMsg;
    tibemsConnectionFactory m_tFactory;
    tibemsMsgProducer m_tProducer;

    //login Credentials
    string m_sJmsServer; //www.test.com
    string m_sJmsUser;   //admin
    string m_sJmsPassword; //123456
    string m_sQueueName;  //MY.QUEUE.REPLY

    /* Create a connection factory. */
      m_tFactory = tibemsConnectionFactory_Create();

    /* Set the server URL */
    m_tStatus = tibemsConnectionFactory_SetServerURL(m_tFactory, sJmsServer.c_str());

    /* Create a connection object */
    m_tStatus = tibemsConnectionFactory_CreateConnection(m_tFactory,
      &m_tConnection, sJmsUser.c_str(), sJmsPassword.c_str());

    /* Create a Destination  */
     m_tStatus = tibemsDestination_Create(&m_tDestination,TIBEMS_QUEUE,m_sQueueName.c_str() 

     /* Create a text message */
     m_tStatus = tibemsTextMsg_Create (&m_tMsg);

     /* Set the data string of a text message  */
     m_tStatus = tibemsTextMsg_SetText(m_tMsg, pszMessage);

     /* Create a Producer  */
     m_tStatus = tibemsSession_CreateProducer (m_tSession,&m_tProducer, m_tDestination);

     /* Create a Session */
     m_tStatus =  tibemsSession_CreateTextMessage(m_tSession,&m_tMsg );
```

Is Code Sequence correct? And Where am I doing wrong? Error Message says that Session is invalid. How can I create a Session for Queue?

Thanks im Advance

Comment: I have solved the Problem with the Function   /* Create a session object  */
  m_tStatus = tibemsConnection_CreateSession(
    m_tConnection,
    &m_tSession,
    TIBEMS_TRUE,
    m_tAckMode
      );